# self healing in centralized logging

Tags: scripting, elastic-stack, self-healing

So I have my centralized logging system setup. But the thing I am currently working on is the self healing in my system. So suppose some error comes up through logs that this service is down. So I need a mechanism/open source tool using which I can write a script that when this type of error comes up, run this script and voila the service restarted/started working fine. 
Thanks